# Checkbox selection not working with pagination

Tags: jquery, datatables

My datatable is displaying 10 records per page and every row it is having check box.

Problem I am facing

1) If I select some of the check boxes in the first page. 
 2) And click on the next page. Now when I come back to the first page whatever the check boxes were selected got unselected but I need them to be selected .

Please suggest.

below is my code

```
    openItemTable = $('#openItems').dataTable(
           {

            "bDestory" : false,
            "bJQueryUI" : false,
            "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
            "bSortCellsTop" : true,
            "aaSorting": [[ sortOpenItems, sortOpenItemsDir ]],
            "bAutoWidth" : false,
            'bLengthChange'  : true,
            "sScrollX": "100%",
            "bScrollCollapse": true,
            "bPaginate" : true,
            "sServerMethod" : "POST",
            "bServerSide" : true,
            "sAjaxSource" : "get_open_items",
            "bProcessing"   : true,
            "bFilter"   : true,
            "fnDrawCallback": initiatecomplete,

           "fnServerData": fnDataTablesPipelineOpenItems,
            "aoColumns" : [

                            {
                                "mDataProp": noteCheckBox,
                                 "bSortable" : false,
                                 "sClass" : "alignCenter",
                                 "fnRender" : function(o, val)
                                    {


                                     ctr = o.iDataRow;
                                       totalreconpage = o.iDataRow;
                                       $("#selectAllCheckBox").prop( "checked", false );
                                       var val = o.aData.invVerNumber;
                                       var number = $.inArray(val, invoiceData);
                                       if(number>-1){
                                           checkedinvoicedata.push(o.iDataRow);
                                       }
                                       if(o.aData.infoSrcTypCode != 'TH' && o.aData.infoSrcTypCode != 'A6'){
                                           disablecheckbox.push(o.iDataRow);
                                        }
                                       if($("#noteCheckBox_"+o.iDataRow).is(':checked')){
                                         return '<input type="checkbox" id="noteCheckBox_'+o.iDataRow+'" CHECKED name="noteCheckBox" />';

                                          }
                                       else{
                                                   return '<input type="checkbox" id="noteCheckBox_'+o.iDataRow+'" name="noteCheckBox" />';
                                       }

                                    }
                            },
```

Comment: Please show your code. Are you using server-side processing mode?

Comment: check out the 'other examples problem/solution' section here: http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/